# Bind To Style Attribute Not Working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have tried to bind `style` attribute on a `div` inside `my-element` to defined property, however the binding doesn't work.

```
<div> hostColor = <span style="{{hostStyle}}">{{hostColor}}</span></div>
```

When I check the inspector, I could see that style attribute has been removed from the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Polymer 1.0, there is new way to [bind to native element attributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding)

so

```
<span style="{{hostStyle}}">{{hostColor}}</span>
```

will become:

```
<span style$="{{hostStyle}}">{{hostColor}}</span>
```